# jquery validation ?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

The plugin works in all other pages in all browsers. In this page plugin working only in IE9 and not in FF, Chrome. In FF, Chrome the form is getting submitted with errors.

i should send my html...i am include my jquery validation but still not working?

```
<script src="../inc/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../inc/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

if page is loded alert working properly... then i should click button there are nor working validation..but file should be exit...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("test");
    // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
    $("#form_page").validationEngine(); 
});
</script>
```

i also send html

```
<form name="form_page" id="form_page" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/1MP1/ap/manufacturer_edit.php">
    <td>
                                                <div class="error_box">
                                                <div class="error_msg"> 
                                                    <img src="images/remove.png" alt=""/>                                                   
                                                </div>
                                            </div>  

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr height="50px">
          <td width="29%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; border-top:1px solid #e9eaeb;" align="right"><span class="addedittitles">Manufacturer Name</span></td>
          <td width="71%" style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; border-top:1px solid #e9eaeb;"><span style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb;"><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <input name="mfgName" type="text" id="mfgName" class="validate[required,maxSize[250]]" value="" maxlength="250" style="width:85%; border:1px solid #cdcdcf; height:22px;"/>
          </span>         
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" align="right"><span class="addedittitles" style="margin-top:10px;">Description</span></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; "><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <textarea name="mfgDesc" id="mfgDesc" class="validate[required]" cols="35" style="width:572px; order:1px solid #cdcdcf; height: 200px;">                                    </textarea>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" align="right"><span class="addedittitles">Website Url</span></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; "><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <input class="validate[required,maxSize[250]]" name="mfgWebsiteURL" id="mfgWebsiteURL" type="text" value="" maxlength="250" style="width:85%; border:1px solid #cdcdcf; height:22px;"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" align="right"><span class="addedittitles">Contact Name</span></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; "><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <input class="validate[required,maxSize[250]]" name="mfgContactName" id="mfgContactName" type="text" value="" maxlength="250" style="width:85%; border:1px solid #cdcdcf; height:22px;"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" align="right"><span class="addedittitles">Phone No</span></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; "><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <input class="validate[required,maxSize[250],custom[phone]]" name="mfgContactPhone"  id="mfgContactPhone" type="text" value="" maxlength="100" style="width:85%; border:1px solid #cdcdcf; height:22px;"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;" align="right"><div class="addedittitles">Email</div></td>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e9eaeb; "><span class="faq_colomn_right">
            <input class="validate[required,maxSize[250],custom[email]]" name="mfgContactEmail"  id="mfgContactEmail" type="text" value="" maxlength="250" style="width:85%; border:1px solid #cdcdcf; height:22px;"/>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
<tr align="right">
    <td height="40px;" align="right" colspan="4"><input name="save" type="submit" id="save" value="Save" class="button1" />                                                     
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="new">
</td>
</tr>  </table>
       </td>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a great validation plugin, called jquery validation, see [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Remember, you should include jQuery BEFORE inclusion of other plugins.

Comment: this code internet exploser still working....but firefox and chorme there are not working

Comment: If you use the above validation plugin it will work in every browser, check the demo here with Firefox or Chrome: http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/

Comment: iam not telling in your demo..above my code still working internet exploser but not working firefox and chorme...how to slove them?